# Need help with this sentence

Tags: word-usage

I'm struggling with the following sentence:

> I'm looking for someone who can help me translate my webpage.

OR

> I'm looking for someone who can help me translating my webpage.

Which one is correct (or better)?

Comment: The [Macmillan dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/help_1) will most likely answer your question. Scroll down to the 'Get it right' section.

Comment: "Help" selects only infinitival clauses as complement, so your first example is fine, but the second one is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 0):

We use the bare infinitive after help when the sentence is active.

> Before I go to school every day, I help my mother **clean** the house.
> (help + bare infinitive when active)

Your first sentence is correct:

> "I'm looking for someone who can help me translate my webpage."

Your second sentence is not correct.  Look at it this way:

<strike>Is there anyone who can help me cleaning the car?</strike>

---

In British English, it is common to use `to + infinitive` after *help*, but it can be dropped.   See Eastwood's Oxford Guide to English Grammar (1994) p. 149:

> After help we can leave out to. *We all helped (to) put up the tent.*

Answer (score 0):

Definitely the second option is correct. i.e " I am looking for someone who can help me translate  my webpage".

Here the infinitive is needed.

You have already used ''I am lookING..'' ,therefore ,the progressive tense has already been used in the sentence.

We use the continuous progressive tense " ...ing" with the verb TO BE in its conjugated form.

Example: I am translating the text.
OR
On arriving at the airport I found my bags gone.

On reading the text I found words missing.

This is because it is a present continuous action-in progress.

Answer (score 0):

Help requires the infinitive, with or without 'to'.

help translate (mostly Am.E.) = help to translate (mostly Br.E.)

Comment: That is true, but you might want to add that in British English the "to" can be dropped.